# Change label color when collectionView Cell is selected in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a filter by type in my app and I did the collectionView setup and everything is working perfectly.

my only problem is making the collectionView cells text labels change color when they are selected to white, and black when they are not.

but it doesn't seem to be working correctly, as it changes the color of a cell that is not selected and does not clear the color after it has been deselected.

Any help with this?

Thank you.

here is my code:

```
var label:UILabel!
var typeText:String?
var type = ["All","Coffee Shops","Pizza Places","Restaurants","Desserts"]


extension HomeTableViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return type.count
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    
        return 1
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
        
        let type = self.type[indexPath.row]
      
        cardView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:myCell.frame.size.width, height:myCell.frame.size.height))
        cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.02)
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
        cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        cardView.layer.borderColor = CGColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.2)
        cardView.layer.borderWidth = 0.4
        cardView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        cardView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:cardView.frame.size.width, height:cardView.frame.size.height))
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.8)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 9, weight: .semibold)
        label.text = type
        
        myCell.addSubview(cardView)
        cardView.addSubview(label)
        
        return myCell
    }
}

extension HomeTableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
 
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      
        typeText = self.type[indexPath.row]
        
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.99, green: 0.71, blue: 0.25, alpha: 1.00) /*ffb233 feb947  fcb53f*/
        backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        backgroundView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.3, height: 0.3)
        backgroundView.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        backgroundView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        backgroundView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        backgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        backgroundView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        backgroundView.clipsToBounds = true

        
       if let selectedCell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath){
        selectedCell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
        label.textColor = .white
        }
}

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cellToDeselect:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
        cellToDeselect.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        label.textColor = .black
    }
```

Comment: *everything is working perfectly.* I doubt that. Be aware that cells are reused and you will add the view and the label again and again in `cellForItemAt` when the user scrolls. The reusable cells are also the reason for your issue. Maintain the selected state in the model.

Comment: @vadian can you provide me with a code snippet or example, or can you provide me with a possible solution to my situation?

Comment: The declaration of the view and the label makes no sense anyway because each cell must have its own individual view and label. Create both UI elements in the method and assign tags. Then first check if the element exists by checking the tag and add the element to the cell only if the check is `false`

Comment: @vadian thank you for your note. but its difficult to translate what you said into actual code. if you can provide a detailed answer i would appreciate it. thank you

Comment: Fixing the subview issue is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not be adding subviews in `cellForItemAt` ... cells are reused, and you end up adding the subviews multiple times in each cell.

Instead, add your subviews in your cell class when it is instantiated.

Then, add this to your cell class:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        label.textColor = isSelected ? .white : .black
    }
}
```

No need to do anything in your controller on `didSelectItemAt` or `didDeselectItemAt`

---

**Edit** -- here is a *very* simple example...

The cell class:

```
class MyCardCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let label: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        return v
    }()
    let cardView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.02)
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
        cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        cardView.layer.borderColor = CGColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.2)
        cardView.layer.borderWidth = 0.4
        cardView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.8)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 9, weight: .semibold)

        [cardView, label].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        cardView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(cardView)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            cardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            cardView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            cardView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            cardView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),

            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.centerYAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),

        ])
    
    }
    
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            label.textColor = isSelected ? .white : .black
            // see the difference between setting
            //      cardView.backgroundColor
            //  or
            //      contentView.backgroundColor
            cardView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor(red: 0.99, green: 0.71, blue: 0.25, alpha: 1.00) : UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.02)
            //contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor(red: 0.99, green: 0.71, blue: 0.25, alpha: 1.00) : UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.02)
        }
    }
}
```

and a sample view controller class:

```
class TestCardCollectionVC: UIViewController {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var type: [String] = ["All","Coffee Shops","Pizza Places","Restaurants","Desserts"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        fl.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        fl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 40)

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0)
        ])

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        collectionView.register(MyCardCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cardCell")

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
    
}

extension TestCardCollectionVC: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return type.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cardCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCardCell
        c.label.text = type[indexPath.item]
        return c
    }

}
```

The output on launch (no cell selected):

[image]

selecting the 3rd cell:

[image]

selecting the 4th cell:

[image]

Comment: how do i create in a cell class? for my requirements? the cardview and the label? id appreciate the help

Comment: thank you so much, this is so useful. and solved my problem and made me understand how to create future sub classess

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find solution using my own project. May be you should try this

```
class NatureCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var natureItemsImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var natureItemsNameLable: UILabel!


// This part you will need. just change the labels name
override var isSelected: Bool {
    
    didSet {
        if self.isSelected {
            self.natureItemsNameLable.textColor = .white
            
        } else {
            self.natureItemsNameLable.textColor = .black
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your cell that subclasses UICollectionViewCell simply set the color highlighted and normal states via the `highlightedTextColor` property on the label.

```
class TypeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

      @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

      override func awakeFromNib() {
         super.awakeFromNib()
         titleLabel.textColor = .white
         titleLabel.highlightedTextColor = .green
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1): Inside cell add view and a label.

2): Create outlet for both.

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel : UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellBgView: UIView!
```

3): In you collectionView cell class paste the following code.

```
 override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.textColor = isSelected ? .white : .black
            cellBgView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .AppRed : .systemBackground
           
        }
    }
```